# Wrong height after switching from landscape to portrait on iOS safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, safari

I've spent hours and dozens of attempts to find out how to calculate the correct height after switching iOS Safari to landscape then back to portrait.

In fact, the height is messed up from the minimal ui mode activation (small bar at the top, no bar at the bottom), that is toggled on after screen rotation.

Here is the broken website:
https://och.design/

Simply try to switch to landscape then to portrait on iOS and you will see that te space where there was the bottom navigation bar stay empty, because its size isn't taken in account in height calculations.

Here is the code I use to calculate a correct `--vh` var for my css on resize events (as suggested at https://css-tricks.com/the-trick-to-viewport-units-on-mobile/):

```
var vh = $.documentHeight() * 0.01;
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`);
```

And finally the code that I use in portrait mode:

```
.main-container{
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
              transform: rotate(-90deg);
      -webkit-transform-origin:top left;
          -ms-transform-origin:top left;
              transform-origin:top left;               
      position:absolute;
      bottom:-100vw;
      height:100vw;
      width: 100vh;
      width:calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100);
};
```

It would be great to be able either to calculate the correct height depending on iOS minimal ui mode on/off or preventing iOS from entering minimal ui mode completely.

Thank you so much in advance!